# xinit: connection to X lost

Tags: nfs

> xinit: connection to X lost server Unable to get the file descripteu.r
>   referring to the console.

After several tests it's pretty weird. I removed the launch of xscreesaver and the problem appears again.

I work in a boot pxe environment with debian and openbox as indicated on the previous message. Each machine mounts the same nfs share ...

In fact it is the last one who is right! This is the last launched that works.

Since all use the same editing nfs the other terminals lose their DIsplay
Currently this worked with a debian of more than 7 years. I'm going to migrate with this new stretch and openbox version ... but nothing works.

```
Xinit.rc :
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
/usr/bin/openbox &
firefox
done

/etc/rc/local :
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo -e "\t Putting the machine into Kiosk mode ...\n"
sleep 3s
rsync -a --delete /home-ro/ /home/
su - userkiosk -c 'startx'
```

In fact, something must be done on a system mounted via nfs so that the X server continues to work on all the computers. For me the system is mounted in memory and should not be a problem! but now I have no idea!

Answer (score 1):

in fact the problem was that some nfs editing data was overwritten!
So you have to mount everything in memory especially / tmp and / home this way all terminals and pc lighter have their own config.

```
#/dev/nfs                     / nfs tcp,nolock 0 0
tmpfs.proc  /proc           proc  defaults,rw,auto 0 0
tmpfs.var   /var            tmpfs
defaults,rw,auto 0 0 tmpfs.run   /var/run        tmpfs
defaults,rw,auto 0 0 tmpfs.log   /var/log        tmpfs
defaults,rw,auto 0 0 tmpfs.tmp   /var/tmp        tmpfs
defaults,rw,auto 0 0 tmpfs.media /media          tmpfs
defaults,rw,auto 0 0 tmpfs.log   /var/log        tmpfs
defaults,rw,auto 0 0 tmpfs.mnt   /mnt            tmpfs
defaults,rw,auto 0 0 tmpfs.root  /root           tmpfs
defaults,rw,auto 0 0 tmpfs.home  /home           tmpfs
defaults,rw,auto 0 0
```